# Using get_the_terms in a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I wrote a lightweight plugin to produce a list of all the terms in a custom taxonomy, which works perfectly. I would like to modify this to produce a list of all the terms for a particular post but I'm struggling with the right way to get_the_terms

```
function antls_taxonomy_list( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
        'name' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'order' => 'ASC',   
    ), $atts);


    $terms = get_the_terms( array(
        'post_id' => '',
        'taxonomy' => $atts['name'],
        'hide_empty' => $atts['hide_empty'],
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => $atts['order'],
        'parent'   => 0
    ) );
```

Full code is as follows (with suggested mods), it's currently generating a 'there has been a critical error on this website' message

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
 
define('ANTLS_PLUGIN_DIR_URL',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

add_shortcode( 'tax_taxonomy_list', 'antls_taxonomy_list' );

function antls_taxonomy_list( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => '',
        'name' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'order' => 'ASC',   
    ), $atts);

    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID, //ID from the $post object
        'taxonomy' => $atts['name'],
        'hide_empty' => $atts['hide_empty'],
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => $atts['order'],
        'parent'   => 0
    ) );

    $html .= '<ul class="antls tax-list-'.$atts['name'].'">';

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            
            if( !empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
                $exclude = explode( ',',$atts['exclude'] );
               if( in_array( $term->term_id, $exclude) ) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
            if( !empty( $atts['include'] ) ) {
                $include = explode( ',',$atts['include'] );
                if( !in_array( $term->term_id, $include) ) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
                
            $html .= '<li class="tax-item-'.$atts['name'].'" data-taxname="'.strtolower( $term->name ).'">';
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

            $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';      
            
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You need pass the post ID to the get_the_terms() function.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the id attribute in the shortcode will do this.

```
//Static
[shortcode id="123"]

//Dynamic. Get the ID of the current post
global $post; //Declare global post variable
 $terms = get_the_terms( array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID, //ID from the $post object
    'taxonomy' => $atts['name'],
    'hide_empty' => $atts['hide_empty'],
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => $atts['order'],
    'parent'   => 0
 ) );
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it causes the same critical error I've been experiencing. I put complete code in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/toomanyairmiles/j1pnuxav/1/. Perhaps the problem isn't where I think it is?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?
Im off out, will reply when I get home.

Comment: 'There has been a critical error on this website.' the wp-die-message. I should do the same, I've been staring at this too long.

Comment: What is the shortcode you are using (including all your atts)

Comment: [tax_taxonomy_list name="category" hide_empty="true" exclude="8" order="ASC"]

Comment: Have you got wp_debug set to true in your wp_config.php file? This should give you a php error that will help you see where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this code [greeting]

  function wp_get_current_cat() 
    { 
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $term_list = get_the_terms($id, 'recipe-category');
//single name
//var_dump($term_list);//multiple
        $cc = $term_list[0]->name;
        return $cc;
    }
    // register shortcode
    add_shortcode('greeting', 'wp_get_current_cat');
```